# JsonObject.GetNamedString is returning &nbsp instead of space

Tags: windows-8

GetNamedString method of JsonObject is returning &nbsp for space. For ex." The String " is returned as &nbspThe String&nbsp. Is there any workaround to fix this issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about running it through [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ee388354.aspx) or [ConvertToText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.html.htmlutilities.converttotext.aspx) - depending on what content you expect in the string:

```
JsonObject s = new JsonObject();
s.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, IJsonValue>("val",  JsonValue.CreateStringValue("&nbsp;The String&nbsp;")));
var t = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s.GetNamedString("val"));
```

By the way, I did have to explicitly put the `nbsp;` in the string to get it to appear, so suspect the JSON you are getting has that embedded (versus it just doing so by default).

Comment: By default Json is converting space to &nbsp. ConvertToText gave me the needed result.